# VisualStudio-2015 - New project from git remote repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I'm a newbie with Visual Studio. So far I was working with eclipse/netbeans and for the last year with Intellij, which are designed rather for java (at least in my opinion).
I've a small project in angular which I store in Bitbucket. I would like to work on it using Visual Studio as I want to add some backend with C# (I'm bored with Java).
I've downloaded Visual Studio 2015 and spent half of the day today (with no luck) trying to clone my angularjs project and display it in VS.
Here is what I've tried:

1. Create new project (Web Application) as described in the first part of this tutorial: http://angularfirst.com/your-first-angular-project-in-visual-studio/

   - then I've opened the Team Explorer and cloned my repository
   - unfortunatelly nothing appeared. I could see only files which were created along with project creation (why so many files describing a project? I cannot understand). I couldn't anyhow display my source files
2. I've firstly opened Team Explorer and cloned my repository. Then I've tried to add a project to this destination. Unfortunatelly I got "**exception from hresult 0x80041fe2**"

   - I couldn't find a proper answer of how to solve this. I've got new laptop (bought 2 days ago), quite fast, and this was my first installation
     of VS on this machine so I skipped all advices about VS reinstallation
3. I've created new project (Web Application) and run "git remote add origin path-to-my-repo" command from gitbash. Still, the same situation as in point 1)

In Intellij or eclipse I can easily add source folders or load a project - then source folders are automatically detected. How can I do it with VS? Or maybe I did it all wrong?

Regards,

misty

Comment: VisualStudio follows a completely different project structure than Java projects....basically you can just create an empty project and then pull from a source and expect that project to work!...you need to first learn the basics: http://angularfirst.com/your-first-angular-project-in-visual-studio/

Comment: Maybe you can do the following; inside the VS project, from `git bash` you can run the following command `git clone route_to_your_bitbucket_project  myAngularApp`...this should clone your repo inside of your project in a folder named myAngularApp....then you can check the `Show All Files` button on VisualStudio: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/05/21/visual-studio-tip-8-adding-existing-files-with-show-all-files/

Comment: Sure, I understand that the project structure is different.
My angular project follows the structure rules from John Pappa (mentioned http://angularfirst.com/your-first-angular-project-in-visual-studio/)
and as far as I saw in screens of this tutorial my structure fits (at least mostly). I also have the "app" folder which is not displayed (why?).
Also, why I can't firstly do the clone and then add the project to this localisation? What does the "exception from hresult 0x80041fe2" means?

Comment: Thanks for the link. The "Show All Files" did not helped. I've tried with "Add->Existing Item" but it only lets me add single file. And I need
to add folders (with cs, js and so on).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround to this. 
In a first place my sources were checkout under /myAngularApp folder. But while creating a project (solution) a subfolder with the same name appeared (despite the fact the checkbox "Create directory for solution" wasn't checked).
So my project structure was:

```
myAngularApp
    - packages
    - myAngularApp
        - bin
        - obj
        - Properties
        - some more files
    - myAngularApp.sln
```

I've checkout the sources to myAngularApp/myAngularApp (initially it was under /myAngularApp). Then I've added such an entry to the csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="app\*\*" />
    <Content Include="e2e-tests\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What I don't like is that it does not automatically detect the subfolders. I've subfolders under /app folder (with css, js and so on) so I needed
to add double "\*\*".

What is worse is that this is only a workaround. I can't belive that creating a project with sources from remote git repository is such a hard
thing in  Visual Studio and needs the manual config file adjustments.
Hope someone will be able to show me the correct solution.

Regards,

misty